# MvvmCross MvxFormsAppCompatActivity: Unable to set FormsApplication property

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm creating an app using Xamarin Forms and MvvmCross, and am inheriting my MainActivity from MvxFormsAppCompatActivity

in the OnCreate method of the MvxFormsAppCompatActivity base class, both the Forms.Init and LoadApplication method are called:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this.ApplicationContext).EnsureInitialized();
    this.LifetimeListener.OnCreate(this);
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    base.LoadApplication(this.FormsApplication);
}
```

and I'm confused how I'm supposed to wedge the initialization of my application if they are called together.

What I mean is, I need to set the FormsApplication property to my actual Xamarin Forms app:

```
this.FormsApplication = new MyFormsApp();
```

But I cannot do this because in order to instantiate the MyFormsApp, I must first call Forms.Init() or I get an exception... but this is already being done in the base OnCreate method.

Should I copy out the code from the base class into my activity and put the assignment between the two statements myself, like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this.ApplicationContext).EnsureInitialized();
    this.LifetimeListener.OnCreate(this);
    Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

    this.FormsApplication = new MyFormsApp();

    base.LoadApplication(this.FormsApplication);
}
```

Even if this works, I'm confused: Why would they set it up this way; how could you possibly load the application before you assign it, but then how can you assign it before you initialize it?

Comment: ah it appears I'm supposed to set this up in the MvxFormsAndroidSetup class. will try that and report back

Comment: You could read this : https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/customize-app